# android maven plugin does not get ANDROID_HOME env variable in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, environment-variables, maven-plugin

i'm working on an Android app project and it is a Maven project.
when i try to run as "maven install" this is what i get:

"Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.1.1:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project android-client: No Android SDK path could be found. You may configure it in the plugin configuration section in the pom file using ... or ... or on command-line using -Dandroid.sdk.path=... or by setting environment variable ANDROID_HOME -> [Help 1]"

if i hardcode my android_home path into pom.xml,it works fine but we use git and everyone may have different paths for android_home.why doesn't android-maven-plugin get env variable in eclipse?

android_home env variable is in my PATH.
i wrote ${env.ANDROID_HOME} in my pom.xml but it still didn't work.

strangely,if i use terminal (mvn install) to run as maven install,it works!

actually this is quite optional problem for me but still i want to know why this plugin does not work in Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a system variable for ANDROID_HOME, not set it in your PATH.

Comment: i did "export ANDROID_HOME=path of the sdk" and added it to PATH. should i did anything else? thanks for answer.

Answer (score 5):

Ensure your Android SDK installation contains the libraries for the **same API version you have configured on your pom.xml**.

For example, if your configuration XML looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <configuration>
        <sdk>
            <path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</path>
            <platform>8</platform>
        </sdk>
        ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

then you should verify with Android SDK Manager (or directly checking on your filesystem: $ANDROID_HOME/platforms) that you have SDK API 8 installed. Of course you can also change your pom.xml to match the library installed.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Linux, exporting the `ANDROID_HOME` in the `.bashrc` may not work.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/toro/etc/android-sdk-linux
```

For me it works only when I export `ANDROID_HOME` in the `/etc/environment` file like this:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/toro/etc/android-sdk-linux
```

<s>You have to restart the computer to get it works.</s>

**You simply have to log out, and log in again** for the environment variable to be applied system-wide.  Optionally, you could just source it locally to test it out before you do that: `$source /etc/environment`

Comment: Generally don't set envs like this (ie you want to use from the desktop apps) in .bashrc - thats why it didnt work for you. In Debian for example I finally nailed it down to sourcing a .bash_env file for system wide ENVs from .xsessionrc - this is sourced *once* at login and all the exports are inherited by further terminals should you need and also available to desktop applications. Should you want these values also available in login shells (e.g ssh'ing in) you would source the same .bash_env from your .bash_profile (which is not sourced at login and has no impact on the desktop ENVs).

Comment: no need to logout in linux Env , just do 
source .bash_profile .
in MAC:
source .profile .

Answer (score 3):

Setting an ANDROID_HOME variable in your .bashrc or whatever will work, but remember to **export** that variable so that it is available to subprocesses. Setting ANDROID_HOME with the other methods suggested here will get you through some initial errors, but without ANDROID_HOME exported your build will probably fail at some point.

Answer (score 3):

on your command line, run:

`mvn clean install -- Dandroid.sdk.path="/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/"`

none of the other methods really worked. (setting `ANDROID_HOME` doesn't do anything)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to set the environment variable into run configuration for pom.xml.

Go to Run Configurations menu,  select the Run configuration used for your project pom.xml and select the *Environment* Tab and select "New",
then insert:

- ANDROID_HOME into name Field
- path to your sdk into value field

It works, and in that way the Variable is set only when you launch the maven configuration for selected projec, and you can also set different path for different projects, and you don't need to change your .bashrc. It work also in windows.

Answer (score 1):

**From the documentation**

You may configure it in the `android-maven-plugin` configuration section in the `pom.xml` file using `<sdk><path>...</path></sdk>` or `<properties><android.sdk.path>...</android.sdk.path></properties>` or on command-line using `-Dandroid.sdk.path=...` or by setting environment variable `ANDROID_HOME`.

**Solution 1**

I have defined an Android SDK system variable called `ANDROID_SDK` (instead of `ANDROID_HOME`) and referenced it in my `pom.xml` this way:

```
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>...</artifactId>
  <version>...</version>
  <packaging>apk</packaging>
  <name>...</name>
  <description>...</description>

  <properties>
    <android.sdk.path>${env.ANDROID_SDK}</android.sdk.path>
    ...
  </properties>
```

**Solution 2**

As an alternative you can also configure it in the `android-maven-plugin` section:

```
<plugin>
<extensions>true</extensions>
<groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
<artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${android-maven-plugin.version}</version>
<configuration>
  <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
  <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
  <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
  <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
  <sdk>
    <android.sdk.path>${env.ANDROID_SDK}</android.sdk.path>
    <platform>16</platform>
  </sdk>
  <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Solution 3**

As a third option you can set the SDK from the command line passing an argument to Maven:

`mvn clean install -Dandroid.sdk.path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Android Development Tools SDK Location path in Eclipse: click on Window -> Preferences and select Android. The SDK Location can be set under Android preferences.

Comment: i'm using m2e android and sdk location is set under preferences.but thanks for answer,and your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called **local.properties** in your root directory of your project.

With the contents;

```
sdk.dir=c:\\path\\to\\android-sdk
```