# Maven plug in could not read ${env.ANDROID_HOME}

Tags: android, maven, ubuntu-14.04

Note:

1) I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Apache Maven 3.2.2, Eclipse Luna Release (4.4.0), ADT Version 23.0.2.1259578, installed m2e plugin for eclipse.

2) Refered to this question [android maven plugin does not get ANDROID_HOME env variable in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415997/android-maven-plugin-does-not-get-android-home-env-variable-in-eclipse)

This is part of my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
    <android.sdk.path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</android.sdk.path>
    <android.sdk.platform>18</android.sdk.platform>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

I have set ANDROID_HOME="my_sdk_path" in /etc/environment

`printenv ANDROID_HOME` in the terminal outputs my SDK path and it is correct.

Problem:

When I run maven build - setting goals as "install android:deploy android:run", it shows that it could not find SDK path. But, when I hardcode as in

```
<android.sdk.path>my_sdk_path</android.sdk.path>
```

as my SDK path in my pom.xml, it works fine.

Seems like ${env.ANDROID_HOME} cannot be read properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting the Android SDK Location in the Android properties in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I did do that. Still did not work.

Comment: Do you get the same problem when you run this from the command line?

Comment: I ran mvn install -e and there is an error showing that "Error reading <my_android_sdk_dir>/tools/source.properties"